# How to grab data from a js script in Jade for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I am trying to grab client side info that was queried already for the server side of a POST. Currently working on a friend button that when clicked POST's to a route file, but I am not sure how to grab the user.id associated with it and send it back to Node.JS.

Here is the jade file includes a for loop that has the user.id  of each person.

```
extends layout
block content   
    div
    legend Search Results
    div#userResults
    for user in ufirstName 
        a(href='/user/#{user.id}')
            p #{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}
        button.addContact Add Contact
```

Here is the route file: I am trying to figure out what to put on the other side of the friendRequest:

```
exports.addContactPost = function(req, res, err) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid,{
                friendRequest: req.body.friendRequest
            }, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("post2");
                    return console.log('error');
                    //return res.render('addContactError', {title: 'Weblio'}); 

                } 

                else {
                    console.log('postsuccess');
                    alert('Contact added');

                }

            });
};
```

This is the script file trying to do the magic:

```
 //Add friends
     $('.addContact').click(function() {
    $.post('/addContact',
       {friendRequest: $(this).data('user')});

    if($(this).html!=='Contact Requested') {
        return $(this).html('Contact Requested');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the ID in the Add Contact link:

```
button.addContact(data-user=user.id) Add Contact
```

Amnd get it in the handler

```
$('.addContact').click(function() {
    $.post('/addContact',
    {
       friendRequest: $(this).data('user');
    } 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok this seems to work, but I am having trouble with using $push: {friendRequest: req.body.friendRequest} to push the request in the friendRequest array, it shows with an error in the route file (the err I have setup in the function)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button.addContact(onclick="addContact('#{user.id}')") Add Contact
```

JS:

```
function addContact(userId){
    $.post('/addContact', { friendRequest: userId }, function(result){
        // use result
    });
}
```